# “If $\tan α + \tan β = 2$ and $\sec α + \sec β = 3$ then find value of $\sin α + \sin β$.”

Tags: trigonometry

If $\tan α + \tan β = 2$ and $\sec α + \sec β = 3$ then find value of $\sin α + \sin β$

On Squaring and subtracting the given two equation, I am getting $2(1− \sin α \sin β)= 3 \cos α \cos β$

Comment: Could you edit into the question what you have tried so far?

Comment: On Squaring and subtracting the given two equation, I am getting.   2(1− sinα sinβ)= 3 cosα cosβ

Comment: Find $\frac{\tan \beta}{\sec \beta}$ and $\frac{\tan \alpha}{\sec \alpha}$ in terms of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ respectively. Then note that $\alpha = \beta$ is a solution to both equations.

Comment: @AshishKumar Are you sure the question as stated is correct?

Comment: Welcome to Math Stackexchange! I am sorry that you are getting such a bad response to your question (downvotes and closure votes). You may expect a better response if you extend your question with something like “I tried [such-and-such approaches, all written out], but they clearly weren't getting anywhere”.

Comment: @TobyMak : If $\alpha=\beta$, then $\tan\alpha=1$ and $\sec\alpha=\frac32\neq\surd2$.

Answer (score 3):

write
$$x=\tan\alpha,\ \ y=\tan\beta$$
Then we get 2 equations
$$\sqrt{1+x^2}+\sqrt{1+y^2}=3\\
x+y=2
$$
with 2 solutions
$$
x=1\pm \frac{3}{2\sqrt5},\ \ y=1\mp\frac{3}{2\sqrt5}$$
From this you can calculate:
$$
\sin\alpha+\sin\beta=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}+\frac{y}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}$$
To get a number we can calculate the angles (for the choice of upper signs in $x,y$):
$$
\alpha=\tan^{-1}x=59.1^\circ\\
\beta=\tan^{-1}y=18.22^\circ
$$
and
$$\sin\alpha+\sin\beta=0.8580..+0.31267..=1.170731..=\frac{48}{41}$$
**Direct Calculation of the exact result**.
Using again the first choice of the upper signs of $x,y$, we note some preliminary calculations:
$$
1+x^2=\frac{49}{20}-\frac{3}{\sqrt5}\\
1+y^2=\frac{49}{20}+\frac{3}{\sqrt5}\\
 {(1+x^2)(1+y^2)}= {\frac{1681}{400}} \\
\sqrt{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)}=\sqrt{\frac{1681}{400}}=\frac{41}{20}\\
x^2+y^2+2x^2y^2=\frac{701}{200}\\
2xy=\frac{11}{10}
$$
Thus:
$$
(\sin\alpha+\sin\beta)^2=\bigg[\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}+\frac{y}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}\bigg]^2=\frac{x^2}{ {1+x^2}}+\frac{y^2}{ {1+y^2}}+\frac{2xy}{\sqrt{1+x^2}\sqrt{1+y^2}}\\
= \frac{x^2+y^2+2x^2y^2}{ (1+x^2)(1+y^2)}+ \frac{2xy}{\sqrt{ (1+x^2)(1+y^2)}} =\frac{\frac{701}{200}}{\frac{1681}{400}}+\frac{\frac{11}{10}}{\frac{41}{20}} 
=\frac{2304}{1681}
$$
and we finally get:
$$
\sin\alpha+\sin\beta=\sqrt{\frac{2304}{1681}}=\frac{48}{41}
$$

Comment: Answer is some constant value.

Comment: Of course. It is a number computable from radicals. I did not see a point in explicitly calculating it.

Comment: $0.8580..+0.31267..\neq1.70731.. .$

Comment: Thanks much - corrected

Comment: I added a direct calulation that shows the exact result

Answer (score 1):

Solve 4 equations  along with sines cosines squared of the two angle identities getting

$$sa^2+ca^2= sb^2+cb^2=1,\; sna/csa+snb/c
sb=2,\; 1/csa+ 1/csb=3\;$$

$$\sin \alpha+ \sin  \beta= \dfrac{48}{41}$$

Comment: Please explain with solution.

Comment: Put all relations together to solve for the four variables as above.